# Calculate the entropy per atom in Bohmian Mechanics

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, bohmian-mechanics

Bohmian mechanics description of a large number of interacting atoms would require a large phase space due to the large number of classical degrees of freedom. The entropy per atom is given as the logarithm of the volume of the phase space of states that are accessible at thermal equilibrium. An atom's heat capacity is close to $k_B$, but Bohm's theory seems to be in conflict with this. If there is a way to compute an atom's heat capacity in Bohm's theory in a natural way that doesn't include some ad-hoc solution which will conflict with other kinds of physics experiments, I'm curious to see the calculation.

Comment: Entropy **of** an atom or entropy **per** atom?

Comment: What's the difference, @JohnRennie ? Well, there could be a difference. The naive application of Bohmian theory doesn't even agree with the fact that the entropy of M+N atoms is additive - because the phase space isn't the  Cartesian product of the two spaces (one needs the space of the pilot waves which is a tensor product, not the Cartesian product needed in a classical theory).

Comment: @LubošMotl: It isn't obvious to me how you can define statistical properties like entropy for a single atom. I'm not saying you can't, because I know nothing about Bohmian mechanics, I'm asking if you can.

Comment: Dear John, well, if you're picky in some way, you can't. You may still define the probability distribution on phase space (or, in QM, density matrix) for a single atom at temperature $T$, right? If you do so, in the canonical ensemble, every atom will individually contribute the same (in correct theories) - the amount "per atom". In a microcanonical ensemble, the low number (one) of atoms will hurt but in the canonical ones, all the extensive quantities are uniformly distributed among atoms.

Comment: Otherwise I won't answer this question officially because I think that there are way too many users on the server who are completely irrational. But the answer obviously is that the entropy of 1 atom or many atoms in any Bohmian theory is clearly infinite as the system has infinitely many classical degrees of freedom. Even with any truncation of them or discretization, the heat capacity will parameterically exceed $O(R)$. It's also the case that there are no papers that make such calculations - the result is inconvenient so the Bohmians, who are dishonest activists, find it better to be silent

Comment: QM is the unique theory that may predict low heat capacities because at low enough temperatures, the number of states (energy eigenstates) whose $E-E_0$ is low enough relatively to $kT$ is small - often one (the ground state is unique). That's why the system carries (almost) no information/entropy, and why the heat capacity is so low. This is only possible because "infinitesimally changed" ground state wave functions don't count as new states - only orthogonal, and therefore very different (and much higher-energy) states are independent, and therefore different.

Comment: Any classical theory - and Bohmian mechanics unavoidably belongs to this set - considers states where the arrangement is "infinitesimally deformed" away from the ground state (e.g. the ground state form of the pilot wave) to be new,mutually exclusive states, which is why the entropy is huge - without regularizations, it's infinite. In classical physics, there was the additive uncertainty $\Delta S$ about entropy. This problem boiled down to the infinite number of points in the phase space. QM was totally needed to make it finite - by dividing phase space to cells $(2\pi\hbar)^N$.

Comment: This division to cells is tied to the fundamental postulates of QM - namely the fact that non-orthogonal states can't be considered mutually exclusive, which is inseparable from the uncertainty principle. ... Even if one had a version of Bohmian mechanics that calculated a finite value of the heat capacity per atom, it would be too huge, and would grow more than linearly with the number of atoms because the configuration space's dimension grows like $\exp(CN)$ rather than $N$ due to the classical waves in the $3N$-dimensional space.

Comment: @LubošMotl What you fail to mention is that the uncertainty principle is completely respected in BM. See Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle section here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Broglie%E2%80%93Bohm_theory#Heisenberg.27s_uncertainty_principle

Comment: It's complete nonsense, a realist theory by definition cannot respect the uncertainty principle. Could you please stop flooding this server by your nonsense? On Schmelzer's website, you have admitted that you have never studied physics for a minute.

Comment: @LubošMotl There's no need to get personal. I admit I've never studies physics, but I'm interested in the philosophy behind it, which is why I ask these questions about realism. My understanding is that in BM the uncertainty principle is a limit of our knowledge about a system, whereas in QM it is due to undefined properties. For example, the position and momentum cannot simultaneously be defined in QM. In BM they are always defined, but you cannot measure them due to some inherent ignorance that will never go away. Best Wishes Lubos.

Comment: @LubosMotl See the 41:00 mark of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lt6PFPKJqZg    to see that even Einstein accepted the uncertainty principle. He was arguing that QM is incomplete, not wrong.

Comment: Everything you write is at least "mostly" wrong. First of all, in the first stage of the Bohr-Einstein debates, Eistein surely did claim that QM was wrong. Then he switched to "incomplete" when his objections were shown bogus. Second, Einstein has never accepted Bohmian mechanics, either, which is why these Einstein quotes are absolutely irrelevant for settling your previous claims about BM and the uncertainty principle. Third, even if Einstein said something about BM and uncertainty principle, it would probably be wrong. Einstein was wrong in most opinions related to QM.

Comment: @LubošMotl Thanks for the history lesson. What matters is the science, and the Wikipedia article shows clearly that the uncertainty principle is valid in BM, so all of your comments about BM and heat capacities failing because of uncertainty not being there in BM is simply wrong.

Comment: @LubošMotl By the way, since you're so keen on discussing history, I thought I would mention that Einstein was fully aware of Dirac's discussion about the low heat capacities. Dirac's book was Einstein's personal favorite on the subject of quantum mechanics, see the link below. Einstein obviously recognized that it ruled out the pre-quantum theories. That's far from saying it ruled out all realist theories, and Einstein fully appreciated this 80 years ago.

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=RRhxNqSkHCoC&pg=PA179&lpg=PA179&dq=einstein+where%27s+my+dirac&source=bl&ots=myGFTpXUI7&sig=va7bK_Qp5Ra5eIXzFKvg2NstK9c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiyjovI_JTNAhWMYCYKHYKeAUEQ6AEIKTAC#v=onepage&q=einstein%20where's%20my%20dirac&f=false

Comment: Bohmian mechanics doesn't rely on classical degrees of freedom. And the expression $S = k_\mathrm{B}\ln {W}$ is in reality an expression derived from a more general definition of entropy. Since Bohmian mechanics gives the same energies and temperatures than wave-formulation, the atoms heat capacity is the same.

Answer (score -1):

One should distinguish here de Broglie-Bohm theory for the general situation outside the equilibrium, and that for quantum equilibrium. Entropy is defined as usual by $H=-\int \rho \ln \rho dq$. Outside the quantum equilibrium it is useful to split it into the entropy relative to the quantum equilibrium $H=-\int \rho \ln (\rho/|\psi|^2) dq$. This relative entropy has been used by Valentini to prove a "subquantum H-theorem" that a general initial distribution will tend toward quantum equilibrium, see for example, http://arxiv.org/abs/1103.1589 for details.

In quantum equilibrium, we have $\rho=|\psi|^2$, so that the formula becomes $H=-\int |\psi|^2 \ln (|\psi|^2) dq$, thus, the standard quantum-mechanical one. After this, you can apply standard quantum theory.

Comment: This is not the quantum mechanical formula for the entropy at temperature $T$. The result is clearly wrong. Just note that it's nonzero even for $T\to 0$. The quantum mechanical for the entropy is the von Neumann entropy $S=-{\rm Tr}(\rho \log \rho)$ and it has the interesting property that $S\to 0$ for $T\to 0$ - something that was known as the third law of thermodynamics even decades before quantum mechanics was born. That's the thing that no classical theory may ever reproduce. Instead of $S\to 0$, you get $S\to \infty$ at all times, a maximally wrong result.

Comment: It would be the von Neumann entropy after a position measurement.

Comment: @Schmelzer - quite the contrary, the von Neumann entropy is the entropy of the state *before* any measurement. After something is measured, extra information gets revealed and the entropy decreases. Extremely, one may measure a complete set of observables. When it's done, the physical system collapses to a pure state $\psi$, and the entropy of any pure state is, in a striking contrast with all your results, zero.

Comment: @Schmelzer - note that I generously overlooked that your correct formula for entropy should have had two terms, one from the pilot wave configuration space and one from the Bohmian position; and that most of your formulae didn't make sense even dimensionally because $\psi$ and $\rho$ are dimensionful so their logarithms have ill-defined units. Your guesses about the entropy simply have nothing whatever to do with the correct (QM or observed) result.

Comment: Lubos Motl is known to be a rabid opponent of dBB theory.  Some of his attacks against dBB theory I have considered in http://ilja-schmelzer.de/realism/Motl.php and http://ilja-schmelzer.de/forum/forumdisplay.php?fid=6  His particular attack related with entropy I have not yet refuted, I plan to do it but have yet some more important things to do.  Anyway, his attacks are unpublished and I would think unpublishable.

Comment: I think this is not the right place to continue this discussion.  What I have described in my answer is the place where a real difference exists (outside the equilibrium), and how this reduces to QM in equilibrium. The entropy is, of course, that of the probability distribution one would obtain if one would measure the configuration q.

Comment: Are you saying that you can go through the ordinary thermodynamic argument from this point and derive the correct heat capacities despite not doing it by reducing to the quantum mechanical calculation? If that's the case then you should probably produce the argument here (or link to something) because "after this you can apply standard quantum theory" is wrong as stated. You're not *at* standard quantum theory yet; as LM noted your entropy is completely different.

Comment: I think it is possible to reduce it to the quantum mechanical calculations.  I would acknowledge that what I have written here is an oversimplification, and that this problem needs a more detailed discussion.  Of course, the von Neumann entropy is 0 for a pure state, but a measurement transforms a pure state into a mixed one, and a position measurement would transform it into a state such that the entropy I have given would be the von Neumann entropy, so it is something close enough.  The details have to be discussed. But I doubt here would be the right place.

Comment: Ilja, none of the statements you are making is correct. For example, in your latest comment, it is not true that a "measurement transforms a pure state to a mixed state". Where did you get this misconception? Your formulae for the entropy aren't "oversimplifications". Instead, they're so wrong that they have nothing at all to do with the correct result. Just try to calculate the numerical magnitude of the heat capacities - which you were supposed to do, anyway. You will see that they have nothing to do with the tiny measured heat capacities.

Comment: If one ignores the result of the measurement, the result is a mixed state.  It is the same mixed state which you can predict before the measurement, if all you know is that the measurement will be done.

Comment: @Schmelzer - As lubos points out, $\rho$ and $\psi$ are dimensionful, so your logarithms are ill defined. Flagging your answer for very low quality is something I considered, but it is really reserved for formatting errors, so I gave you a pass. Sorry, but your answer is utter nonsense, and 10th grade students are familiar with enough math to know that your logarithms are ill defined.

Comment: Motl's argumentation is unpublished ...,  I have, essentially, given a short reference to Valentini's subquantum H-theorem, which is published research, and seems relevant, because it is something about the domain where dBB and QT is really different - the domain outside quantum equilibrium.  This is not the adequate place to show that Motl's thermodynamic argument is nonsense. Just think about it:  If the theories are proven to be equivalent (they are, see Bohm 1952), how can the statistical approximations appear inequivalent?

Comment: And, of course, this is also not the place to give a detailed definition of entropy.  In the case of a continuum of values, one needs, of course, a prior, and what is under the logarithm is the relation between the probability density and the prior.  $\rho dq/dq$.

Comment: @Schmelzer No, they are not equivalent. They have different mathematical formulations. They agree for a large, but relatively small subset of quantum mechanical phenomena, e.g. double slit for example. BM doesn't work as a QFT, and as Motl pointed out it doesn't work for heat capacities.

Comment: @Schmelzer Actually, it is the place to show that Motl's argument is nonsense. That's precisely what my question asks. I think what you meant to say was that you can't show how to compute heat capacities in BM, hence the excuse.

Comment: @Schmelzer  The H-theorem is about where dBB and QT are different ... the theories are proven to be equivalent (see Bohm 1952). You brilliantly found a way to contradict yourself within a few sentences.

Comment: The theories are different in the general case.  They are equivalent only in a particular case - in the quantum equilibrium.  Valentini's H-theorem proves that this quantum equilibrium will be reached in a way similar to Bolzmann's H-theorem proves that thermal equilibrium will be reached. To show that Motl is wrong needs, unfortunately, a longer introduction into the basics of thermodynamics, one which makes it clear from the start, that equivalent theories have to lead to equivalent thermodynamics.    This is nothing I can do in a few comments, sorry.

Comment: They are different, but in quantum equilibrium they make the same predictions about observable effects.  And the first Bohmian example of an RQFT you can find for the EM field in Bohm 1952.  So that the claim that dBB is unable to handle a QFT is nonsense from the start.

Comment: @Schmelzer - I was happy to see that you got so entangled in your bizarre claims about equivalence and inequivalence that even user7348 could see it very clearly. The claim that the theories are "equivalent in equilibrium" is clearly false but even if it were correct, it would still change nothing about these matters. user7348 could ask you to calculate any non-equilibrium parameter - e.g. a diffusion coefficient - and you would be lost again, generating even more hopelessly incorrect expressions than you did here.

Comment: Find the error in Bohm's 1952 paper and publish it in a peer-reviewed journal.  Then we can talk again about equivalence or not.  I'm not more interested in discussing unpublished inequivalence claims about dBB than in claims about logical errors in SR.  BTW, the two theories are equivalent in quantum equilibrium, which has nothing to do with thermodynamic equilibrium.  All QM predictions are, by definition of the Born rule, in "quantum equilibrium", a term which makes really sense only in dBB theory itself, where different states are possible.

Comment: @Schmelzer  I'm not a physicist. I'm asking these questions because I'm incompetent to answer them myself, but I'm just curious if there's some alternative to the standard QM approach. So, I've asked Motl to account for Bohm (1952) as you have, but I'm also asking tough questions of you. Put your money where your mouth is. Calculate the diffusion coefficient as Motl asks using a BM approach. Show me loop corrections, and all the other things Motl mentions on his blog. Publish these results in a peer reviewed journal.

Comment: The computations you ask for are trivial and well-known, so, not at all tough. Because I simply use the Bohm 1952 equivalence result, thus, immediately obtain the information that the result is the same as in QM, where it is well-known.  Well-known results are no longer publishable, because scientific articles should contain something new.  So, if, say, you would compute such things and submit this, and I would have to review it, I would reject it because it contains nothing new in comparison with Bohm 1952.